How to solve pyinstaller dependency issues while creating build?
I have created a small project using FastAPI. and I want to create a build of that using pyinstaller. Also, I have an env for this project and I am activating that before creating the build.
below is my build.py file
import PyInstaller.__main__
import spacy
import logging
# Load the en_core_web_lg model
logging.getLogger('PyInstaller').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

# Get the path to the model data
model_data_path = spacy.util.get_package_path('en_core_web_lg')
print(model_data_path)
PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'main.py',
    '--name=myapp',
    '--onefile',
    '--hidden-import=uvicorn',
    '--collect-submodules=tensorflow',
    '--hidden-import=tensorflow',
    '--collect-data=tensorflow',
    '--collect-all=spacy',
    f'--add-data={model_data_path}:en_core_web_lg',
])

requirement.txt
tika==2.6.0
uvicorn==0.27.0.post1
presidio_analyzer[transformers]
transformers==4.37.2
tensorflow==2.15.0.post1
python-multipart==0.0.9
redis==5.0.1
python-dotenv==1.0.1
cryptography==42.0.1
fastapi==0.109.0
psycopg2==2.9.9
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
psutil==5.9.8

When I am running build.py file I am getting the below errors, below only are fewer I am getting lot of import errors from tensorflow.
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.activations' not found
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications' not found
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.convnext' not found
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.densenet' not found
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.efficientnet' not found
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2' not found
80425 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.imagenet_utils' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_v3' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.nasnet' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.regnet' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_rs' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_v2' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg19' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.xception' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks' not found
80426 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.constraints' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.boston_housing' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar10' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar100' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.imdb' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.mnist' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.reuters' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.estimator' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.experimental' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.export' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.initializers' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers.experimental' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.losses' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.metrics' not found
80427 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.models' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.legacy' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.schedules' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.image' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.sequence' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.text' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.regularizers' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.saving' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.utils' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.keras.utils.legacy' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.nn.layers' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.nn.layers.experimental' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.rnn_cell' not found
80428 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v1.v1' not found
80430 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator' not found
80430 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.experimental' not found
80430 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.export' not found
80430 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.inputs' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.tpu' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.estimator.tpu.experimental' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.layers' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.legacy' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.legacy.layers' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.legacy.layers.experimental' not found
80431 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.__internal__.legacy.rnn_cell' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.activations' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.convnext' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.densenet' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.efficientnet' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.imagenet_utils' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2' not found
80432 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.inception_v3' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.mobilenet_v3' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.nasnet' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.regnet' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet50' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_rs' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.resnet_v2' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg16' not found
80433 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.vgg19' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.applications.xception' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.backend' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.callbacks' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.constraints' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.boston_housing' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar10' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.cifar100' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.imdb' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.mnist' not found
80434 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.datasets.reuters' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.estimator' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.experimental' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.export' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.initializers' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers.experimental' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.losses' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.metrics' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.mixed_precision' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.models' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers' not found
80435 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.legacy' not found
80436 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.optimizers.schedules' not found
80436 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing' not found
80436 ERROR: Hidden import 'tensorflow._api.v2.compat.v2.compat.v1.keras.preprocessing.image' not found

I am not sure what I am getting wrong.
